# The localhost page isn’t working in laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use Input; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Requests; 
use App\models\Designation; 
use Validator;
class Cdesigination extends Controller
{
   public $flight;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->flight = new Designation; 
    }
    public function index(request $request)
    {   
        $this->flight->name = $request->name;
        $this->flight->detail = $request->detail;
        $this->flight->token_key = $request->_token;
        $data=$this->flight->save();
        if($data){
        return Redirect::to('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Inserted Successfully.');
        }
        else {
         return Redirect::to('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Not inserted Successfully.'); 
        }
     return view('designation');
    }
}
```

Here is route code:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');
```

Where is trouble and how to solve it?

I think redirect keyword create trouble because when i raze the `redirect:: to` keyword then working fine.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'localhost isn't working'. Does your test page appear ? By raze do you mean erase ?

Comment: when i comment this code    return Redirect::away('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Inserted Successfully.');
        }
        else {
         return Redirect::away('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Not inserted Successfully.'); 
        }   working fine otherwise show     The localhost page isn’t working

Comment: remove withInput() and try

Comment: Share your error log, if you don't see any error log, set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file

Comment: Also, the heading of this question doesn't make sense

Comment: this error show  The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try:
Reloading the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're going to `/posts` which uses `Cdesigination@index` action. And this action always redirects to the same page, to itself. And it will be redirected to itself again and again and again.

So `view('designation')` will never be loaded:

```
if ($data) {
    // If $data is true, redirect
    return Redirect::to('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Inserted Successfully.');
} else {
    // If not, redirect too
    return Redirect::to('posts')->withInput()->with('success', 'Not inserted Successfully.'); 
}

// Any code here will never be executed
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, but if you want to load `designation` view with messages, you should do something like this:

```
if ($data) {
    // If $data is true, redirect
    return view('designation')->withInput()->with('success', 'Inserted Successfully.');
} else {
    // If not, redirect too
    return view('designation')->withInput()->with('success', 'Not inserted Successfully.'); 
}
```

Comment: @GhulamAbbas, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but I've tried to give you a hint. Check updated answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the Redirect. You are using `withInput()` and `with('success', 'Inserted Successfully.')`. Use any one. You might want to erase withInput() and try. Also do you not get laravel errors displayed on your page ?